# Oracle Apex - Create Button,select and Upload file from CSV into APEX Table, Display in the application page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am new to Apex development, I want to add a button to an existing page on Apex.
This button should be able to browse a file(.CSV), the data from the .csv should get inserted to the Apex table.

Can anyone please provide me the steps and the scripts to achieve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Create page". Among all page types, you'll notice the **Data loading** type so - select it. Follow the Wizard.

The result will be 4 pages that are called one after another, and will let you do what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try this out. Also, will I be able to link this to a Button.. ie., When the Button(name: Upload CSV) is clicked, this redirects me to Data loading page and so on.. thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. As of a button: no problem, you can redirect to any page you want (including data loading).

Comment: Hi, I was able to achieve the Data loading Wizard, thank you for that.
I wanted to have a column modified before the insert, so I used Table lookups(while creating the data loading) and I am receiving the below error.

Comment: Error during rendering of region "Data / Table Mapping".
ORA-01403: no data found

Technical Info (only visible for developers)
is_internal_error: true
apex_error_code: APEX.REGION.UNHANDLED_ERROR
ora_sqlcode: 100
ora_sqlerrm: ORA-01403: no data found
component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGES
component.id: 89498000000029
component.name: Data / Table Mapping
error_backtrace:
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_DISP_PAGE_PLUGS", line 997

Any pointers, please ?

Thank you.